# Can the error term involved in the PNT be expressed in a Galois theoretic framework?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, riemann-hypothesis

According to Wikipedia, the current best error term for the prime number theorem is $\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)=O\left(x\exp\left(-\frac{A(\ln x)^{3/5}}{(\ln\ln x)^{1/5}}\right)\right)$, while RH is equivalent to $\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)=O(\sqrt{x}\ln x)$. Can these two error terms be expressed in a Galois theoretic framework, namely would the expression inside the big $O$ be an element of some extension of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$? If so, could we give a rigorous argument explaining why the error term under RH is in itself simpler than the unconditional one, hence giving further evidence towards the truth of RH?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on what one can read in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29, it seems that the error term under RH lies in $\mathbb{C}(x,\sqrt{x},\ln x)$ while the currently known best error term lies in a bigger extension of $\mathbb{C}(x)$. Am I right?

Comment: Not exactly. My goal is to connect both algebraic and analytic points of view so as to give an a priori form for the (best possible) error term. My guess is that the "real" error term (say $f(x)$ such that $\frac{\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)}{f(x)}$ is bounded but doesn't tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, so that $f$ is defined up to a multiplicative constant) can't lie in too big a differential extension of $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: In other words, I aim at determining the minimal differential extension $K$ of $\mathbb{C(x)}$ such that there exists $f(x)\in K$ such that $\frac{\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)}{f(x)}$ is bounded but doesn't tend to $0$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I should have written $\mathbb{C}(x)$ or $\mathbb{R}(x)$ instead of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. As for the quotient not being convergent, Littlewood proved that $\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)$ changes sign infinitely often, so that under RH, there exists $C>0$ such that $-C<\frac{\pi(x)-\mathrm{Li}(x)}{\sqrt{x}\ln x}<C$. By the way, what is the "damp function"?

Comment: see also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154373/differential-galois-number-theory